# Load and save to url with the Monaco editor

Tags: monaco-editor

I'm using the Monaco editor to edit files hosted by a server and loaded with GET and saved with PUT (whole file) and PATCH (using Google `diff-match-patch`). I haven't hooked up the editor with the real files yet, just testing with hardcoded strings. I'm using `monaco.editor.create` with `{ value: 'some code', language: 'csharp' }`. My question is if the editor itself perhaps already have features for this, or if there are plugins that do this? I mean to load and save editor-content from/to a url (with http verbs).

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing like that. The entire interaction with the code happens via the model. There's neither file nor network support in the editor. It's an editor control, not a full-fledged editor application.